# How to group a certain character in regex expression?

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

This is my regex expression

```
/(')([\w\ \,\"]+)(')/g
```

I want to group the \" individually so I can replace it with some other character later, how do I do that?

Sample https://regex101.com/r/mqO4yL/1

Comment: What do you mean by `replace it with some other character later` ?

Comment: I don't think you mean replace the `"` with a `'` at the time of construction. So, the answer is _you can't slice it up so just the " is isolated in a group, for later replacement._ All the answers given are wrong.

Comment: You can't the grouping is that entire character set.  What you are talking about is conditional logic.  That is outside the scope of what any regex is capable of doing.

Comment: You should not modify JSON using regex, this approach almost never works. If you need to fix some JSON, make the JSON provider fix it on their side.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of hard to know for sure without an example of the text you'd being using in the regex.  But based on what it looks like it's trying to do if you had something like:

```
/'"test"'/g
```

or

```
/'test"'/g
```

You could use:

```
/(')((\w|\ |\,)*(\")*)*(')/g
```

and the fourth group would get you the double quotes.  There might be an easier way without so many groups but without an example text I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that we want to capture `"` only and everything else then replace it. Maybe, this expression would be an option:

```
([\s\S]*?)(")?
```

[image]

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7bWyZk/1/)